# Combining graphics with manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate

For the code below, I am trying to make it such that when I go through $\alpha$ values, the plot updates. However, currently, it just plots with a stagnant $\alpha$ value with no updating. When I try to redefine everything in terms of a function of $\alpha$, mathematica tells me that I cannot use graphics and define variables. For instance, I cannot write plotcoordinates[$\alpha$] due to the limitations of graphics. How can I get around this to have the plot update as I wish in the slide bar?

```
plotcoordinates = 
  Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], {Dashed, 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {x1, x2, x3}}]}, {Dashed, 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}, {Dashed, 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}}, Boxed -> False];

Voriginal = {1, 0, 0};
Rz = {{Cos[\[Alpha]], -Sin[\[Alpha]], 0}, {Sin[\[Alpha]], 
    Cos[\[Alpha]], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};

Vector = Rz.Voriginal;
x1 = Vector[[1]];
x2 = Vector[[2]];
x3 = Vector[[3]];

Manipulate[plotcoordinates, {\[Alpha], 0, 2 \[Pi], 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly the following is what you want to see

> [image: gif]

The code:

```
Voriginal = {1, 0, 0};
Rz = {{Cos[a], -Sin[a], 0}, {Sin[a], Cos[a], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
Vector = Rz . Voriginal;
x1 = Vector[[1]];
x2 = Vector[[2]];
x3 = Vector[[3]];
plotcoordinates =
  Graphics3D[
   {Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}],
    {Dashed, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {x1, x2, x3}}]},
    {Dashed, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]},
    {Dashed, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}},
   Boxed -> False];
Manipulate[
 Evaluate[plotcoordinates], {a, 0, 2 π, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: thank you SO much

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber glad I was able to help :)